# What is the difference between SDK and Application?

Tags: sdk, difference

**what are the difference between SDK and Application.**

> This question may be silly for someone but sometime
>   myself getting confuse by vendor e-mails about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer this in short form:

Application (or app) is something that performs an activity (or activities) for a user to accomplish something.

SDK helps you to build the application.

Comment: thanks for your replay. If a zip file contains an application, manuals, drivers files then can we call that is SDK?